# useLocation hook and Server Side Rendering error in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

In one of my pages I want to get the `page` number param from the path and to do it I am using the `useLocation` hook imported from `@reach/router`.

```
import { useLocation } from '@reach/router';
```

The path looks like this:

> ```
> http://localhost:4000/joboffers/?page=7
> ```

And I am getting the page number from the path like follows:

```
const pageParam = Number(useLocation().search?.split('=')[1]);
```

Well, if I `console.log` the `pageParam` variable, in the console of the Browser I get the correct page number, BUT if I check the terminal in Visual Studio Code the value of the same variable is `NaN` and Gatsby throws the following error:

> React Components in Gatsby must render both successfully in the
> browser and in a Node.js environment. When we tried to render your
> page component in Node.js, it errored.

Does anyone know why is that happening? If I skip the SSR everything is working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you perfectly spotted the issue. In the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) the [`window` and other global objects are not defined yet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) (for obvious reasons, you are in the server, not in the client) so any reference to that variables will fail.

The solution (one of the many possibilities) is that simple as:

```
let pageParam;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  pageParam = Number(useLocation().search?.split('=')[1]);
} else {
   pageParam = 0;
}
```

This only happens during the `gatsby build` because `gatsby develop` command runs the project in the client directly (summarizing a lot).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now Gatsby is not throwing any error, but the pagination component is not working as expected. For example, if the path is "/joboffers/?page=5" and I refresh the page (F5), the pageParam variable is = 5 in the Browser console and = 1 in the node terminal.  :-(

Comment: You'll never be able to get client parameters in a node console directly without sending them somehow https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/adding-pagination/